# Footer over image source

Tags: html, css

The footer does not show the image above the footer.

#### Screenshot:

Image is under footer

[image]

#### Source Code

```
.footer-area {
  background-position:  center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5; }

.footer-area::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50pc;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.svg);
  background-position:  center;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS we need to reproduce the issue please. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The attribute z-index will not be applied to the pseudo element `:before`, if you want image in the front layer, you have to apply the `z-index` in the before element